# Move/Resize Variables Explorer in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

How can I customize the location and size of the Variables Tab in VSCode so I can move it to a split screen?
If that is not possible, how can I run 2 instances of VSCode with the same kernel so the variable explorer only eats up space in the second screen? Is there a better workaround than this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible, and as of now, [no plans to improve the situation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5283).